# Assign code to a specfic form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to submit  a variable on form1 using jquery which at the end disables the submit button for this form with a message "Sent Successfully".

There's another form on the page called form2  which is assigned an action to submit variables to another page without ajax call but i think my button disable code is conflicting with the form2 not making it able to send the variables to the assigned action page.

```
<script language="javascript">
/**
 * Disable submit button
 */
$(function(){
      $('input:submit', '#form1').click(function(){
            $(this).val('Sent Successfully...');
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      });
});
</script>
```

form2

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" method="post" action="search.php">
          <label for="textfield"></label>
          <input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" />
          <input type="submit" name="button2" id="button2" value="Submit" />
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

yes it deflects because you're using two selectors, one that will disable all the submit buttons and then `#form1`. try changing it to:

```
$(function(){
      $('#form1').click(function(){
            $(this).val('Sent Successfully...');
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `#form1`. Just use `input:submit` to target the button and it should work. Keep in mind that this will also apply to the submit button of form 2 i.e when you click submit in form2 it will change the text and disable it.

```
$(function(){
      $('input:submit').click(function(){
            $(this).val('Sent Successfully...');
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      });
});
```

Comment: it doesn't send to the action and also doesn't disable the other button when sent

Comment: My bad i seem to have mistaken that for a class -_-.I have update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `input:submit` this will disable all the submit button in that particular page.

Instead of this

```
$(function(){
  $('input:submit', '#form1').click(function(){
        $(this).val('Sent Successfully...');
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

Try using:

```
$(function(){
  $('#form1').on('click','input:submit',function(){
        $(this).val('Sent Successfully...');
        $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
});
```

Comment: changes the button successfully but when i click on send in form2, nohting happens

Comment: i've noticed something, there is "event.preventDefault();" in the ajax call that i use for the submission. that is not making it to work. is there a way around?

Comment: can you share the code used in the ajax or make `event.preventDefault();` specific to `#form1` only.

Answer (score 0):

Just try with `submit` event, and select the appropriate button with [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method:

```
  $( '#form1' ).on( 'submit', function() {
      $(this)
          .find( '#button1' )
          .val( 'Sent Successfully...' )
          .attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
  });
```